# Jquery .push gives weird output: '[[[[{....}]'

Tags: javascript, jquery, push

I am developing a salesreport system which is heavily relying on JSON communication. I have a script that records client visits into a Javascript Object. Which works fine, apparently.

```
salesReport = [];
...
salesReport.push({
    "nr": visitCounter, 
    "kto":  ActiveAccount,
    "dok": dokName 
 });
```

Each time a visit is logged the push function is activated.
Onthe first run I get the expected result:

```
[{"nr":1,"kto":"52803","dok":""}]
```

But when I push again, I get this result:

```
[[[[[{"nr":1,"kto":"52803","dok":""}],{"nr":2,"kto":"52350","dok":""}],  {"nr":3,"kto":"52539","dok":""}],{"nr":4,"kto":"50869","dok":""}],{"nr":5,"kto":"52135","dok":""}]
```

The '[' brackets are added at the beginning of the output, and at the end of each post. Why is that ?

Shouldn't the '[' and ']' only be added at the beginning and at the end? and then only one time ?

Comment: Show us the complete function.

Comment: Are you sure not using: `[].push([])`?

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems there was an idiotic error in another script.
At the end of each session the visitor log is stored in a local storage file. Which is then read back into the javascript Object if another session is started the same day.

The problem was that I had used the .push function to read the "old" data back into the object. Thus creating a double push of sorts which led the system to think that it was all one entry instead of several entries.

So in the end it was "my bad".

logging this in case someone else in the future might experience the same thing.